# generating serializable cs classes from xsd : which tool use?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

i need to define some classes that implement a third party xsd definitions . The xsd is quite complex , with a lot of restrictions end enumerations, Therefore i've tried to save a bit of time using xsd.exe and xsd2code. However generated classes don't take into account the minoccurs=0 attribute and , worst, maps to an enum (int) some types defined as string. For example the type below is mapped as an enumeration with the same name :

```
<xsd:element name="CodiceFornitura">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="IMP00"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public enum CodiceFornitura
    {
        /// <remarks/>
        IMP00,
    }
```

The other problem is that some element migth or might not be serialized :for example if i'm sending a type of document (say OriginalInvoiceUpdate), i must add a piece of xml that states which invoce has to be replaced otherwise that piece of xml must be omitted.

xsd2code has two properties to generate code : GenerateShouldSerialize and GeneratePropertyNameSpecified. Setting the first to true don't have any effect, setting the second to All generates the properties for all class memmbers , not only for thats with minoccurs=0.

So the questions are  :
1. shall i change the generated sources to reflect my needs, there are some configurations i'm missing with xsd.exe or xsd2code ? 
2. what XmlSerializer will write into the xml for enums : the enumeration value ("1") or the string representation of the value (IMP00) ?
3. there are other tools to build sources from xsd ?

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: You can, of course, read the XML Schema into memory, and generate your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx). It has options to generate classes from xsd and is a lot more configurable than xsd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

We use [LinqToXsd](http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/)
And [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/)